# How to clone HDD to an SSD (OS) and HDD (Data)

Tags: windows, ssd, cloning

Is it possible to clone an HDD by moving the OS to a target SSD and all the data to an HDD?

I have a laptop (Let's call it laptop A) running Windows 10 with a 1TB HDD which has very important customizations and data. I have another laptop (let's call it B) with a 128GB SSD and 1TB HDD. I'd like to clone laptop A to laptop B with laptop A's OS ending up on laptop B's SSD and the rest of the data on the HDD.

I don't know if this is possible or not. I'm wondering what operating system files would need to be moved.

Has anyone ever done this before or have any idea how? Thanks.

**Edit: Added images**

**Laptop A**
[image: Laptop A]

**Laptop B**
[image: Laptop B]

Comment: You forgot to add the size of Laptop A's disk. If it's <128GB just clone the entire disk to SSD B and afterwards move the data from SSD B to HDD B

Comment: 1TB HDD. And I edited the question.

Comment: All on the same partition, I reckon? I believe a new installation of W10 on the new Laptop and then mounting HDD A on Laptop B to copy the data would be the "fastest" way. If you have two partitions: you can clone only the OS partition to a new drive.

Comment: @Lenniey You know what. I'm not sure. I have to check again. If I recall correctly there might be a hidden boot partition. I come back here once I check.

Comment: @Lenniey Ok. So, I was able to check after coming back from work. They're on the same partition. But how would that method work since OS components might have the *"C":\* path imprinted in them?